# Python : Plotting outlier using plt

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scikit-learn, outliers

I am performing outlier detection on a dataset having six columns.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   166 11.3    0.37    15.8    14.7    251
1   165 11.4    0.37    15.9    15.4    254
2   168 11.2    0.38    14.7    14.2    248
3   168 11.1    0.38    14.1    15.0    248
4   170 11.1    0.37    14.3    15.6    250
```

Then, I used Isolation forest from sklearn as shown below.

```
ifo = IsolationForest(n_estimators=100, max_samples='auto', contamination=0.1, max_features=1.0,bootstrap=True, n_jobs=-1, random_state=None, verbose=2)
ifo.fit(X)

Out[39]:
array([ 0.1147684 ,  0.0967917 ,  0.12101755, ...,  0.07251437,
        0.07300837,  0.03996958])
ifo_preds = ifo.predict(X)
```

1. There is a contamination variable in Iso Forest, it is default to 0.2, if I don't know how many outliers are there, should I use it as default or the approach should be different.

Next, I want to plot the outliers on a graph as shown in  sklearn example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor

np.random.seed(42)

# Generate train data
X = 0.3 * np.random.randn(100, 2)
# Generate some abnormal novel observations
X_outliers = np.random.uniform(low=-4, high=4, size=(20, 2))
X = np.r_[X + 2, X - 2, X_outliers]

# fit the model
clf = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=20)
y_pred = clf.fit_predict(X)
y_pred_outliers = y_pred[200:]

# plot the level sets of the decision function
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 50), np.linspace(-5, 5, 50))
Z = clf._decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

plt.title("Local Outlier Factor (LOF)")
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Blues_r)

a = plt.scatter(X[:200, 0], X[:200, 1], c='white',
                edgecolor='k', s=20)
b = plt.scatter(X[200:, 0], X[200:, 1], c='red',
                edgecolor='k', s=20)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.xlim((-5, 5))
plt.ylim((-5, 5))
plt.legend([a, b],
           ["normal observations",
            "abnormal observations"],
           loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

Which gives the output as shown in the figure.

[image]

How can i plot this to fit my example. 
I am also attaching link to my dataset.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GFTVTObsZEAQ7d49Ajtnz_GfVMgKOtt_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Why is this tagged `Python3.x` and `Python2.7`? Which one is it? And I would include the tag `matplotlib`.

Comment: it is working in both python versions, I have checked